# How should I set up angular for node.js in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

NG open --serve it shows some security error when I enter this in the terminal

Comment: I have posted the answer if that solves your question please modify your question accordingly. Thank You

Comment: When you post a question you'll want to be as specific as possible. "Shows some security errors" doesn't provide any useful information. Can you copy/paste the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write before every Angular Command `npx`. It is the execution package of npm. So if you want e.g. to serve your Angular Application you can write `npx ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to run Angular Application then run
`ng serve`